# detect rising edge and falling edge to assing signal to Enable

Tags: vhdl, synchronous

I'm trying to create a process that detect the first rising edge of PGOOD signal and turn on ENABLE.
Then I need to detect the first falling edge of PGOOD and turn off ENABLE for good.
Here is what I tried but it doesn't work - the ENABLE is always '0'.
 what am I missing?

```
process(PGOOD,CPLD_RESETn)
begin
if (CPLD_RESETn = '0')  then
             off <= '0';
elsif (falling_edge(PGOOD)) then
             off <=  '1';
end if;
end process;


process(PGOOD,CPLD_RESETn)
begin
if (CPLD_RESETn = '0')  then
             firstOn <=  '0';
elsif (rising_edge(PGOOD)) then
             firstOn <=  '1';
end if;
end process;

ENABLE <= firstOn and not(off);
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - it might help if you told us what problem or error you are seeing.

Comment: sorry - edit the Q.
ENABLE always '0'

Comment: What you are missing is another input or edge count.  You cannot have the same input edge perform two different actions (Enable and Ignore) without another input (POR, Reset) or a volatile memory register.

Comment: `PGOOD` is not a clock signal, so you can not use `rising_edge` and `falling_edge` function in VHDL! You need to implement an edge-detection circuit in VHDL using 1 FF, 1 NOT and 1 AND gate.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I don't see anything wrong in your code. Your requirement seems to be met when I simulated the code. Enable went high on the first rising edge and went down when it detected the first falling edge afterwards. I think you forced the inputs in a wrong way.

Comment: That's because you don't simulate what's going on in hardware. You simulation model does not match reality.